# string to Xml conversion

Tags: c#, xml

How to convert the following string to xml ?

```
 var query = @"<Cars><Car manufacturer='lindo'/>
               <Car manufacturer='Opera'/></Cars>";
```

As it is a string i can't apply the extension method .cast() to convert it to XDocument or XElement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) method.

Comment: When in doubt, if you have a `string` and you want to make a `Something` from it, look for a method named `Something.Parse`.

Comment: @Jason Really a valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var queryXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + query;
 var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.LoadXml(queryXml);
```

(Cars will be your root element).

Comment: why the closing tag </xml> is not allowed when i put "<?xml..> <Cars><Car>....</Car> </xml>"

Comment: @Dina because (a) there is no "opening tag" and (b) "xml" in any capitalization is reserved in XML

Comment: @Dina: the ?xml is not the opening tag for the xml document. It is like a header. You need to have <?xml...><xml>...</xml>

Comment: @Dina you actually need `</Cars>`